# Find match between 2 columns of different files and replace third with awk

Tags: awk

I am looking for a way to replace a column in a file, if two `ID` columns match.
I have file `A.txt`

```
c     a   b   ID
0.1  0.01 5   1
0.2  0.1  6   2
0.3       2   3
```

and file `B.txt`

```
ID   a   b
1   10   15
2   20   16
3   30   12
4   40   14
```

The output im looking for is
file `A.txt`

```
ID a    b   
1  0.01 5   
2  0.1  6   
3   30  2
```

I found out that it is possible with the following

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ if(NR>1) a[$1]=$2; next }
     FNR>1 && $1 in a && NF<3{ f=$2; $2=a[$1]; $3=f }1' B.txt A.txt | column -t
```

But the problem is that it compares $1 from both files. How can i instead compare `$4` from `A.txt` with `$1` from `B.txt`

I tried the following

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ if(NR>1) a[$1]=$2; b[$1]=$1; next }
     FNR>1 && $1~ /b[$1] in a && NF<3{ f=$2; $2=a[$1]; $3=f }1' eaf.txt final.txt | column -t
```

But it didnt work. Is there a way to solve it? Thank you

Comment: It's customary to comment when downvoting.

Comment: You need to specify the `FS` (use for example tab and `FS="\t"`) as `A.txt` does not have $2 when `NR==4` when you are using the default `FS`. Other than that this should suffice: `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}$4 in a{print $4,$2,$3}' B A`.

Comment: You need to tell us if `A.txt` is tab-separated or fixed-width fields or something else otherwise how can we write a tool to figure out that the missing value on line 4 is the 2nd one?

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ if(NR>1) a[$1]=$2; next }
     FNR==1{ print $NF,$2,$3; next }   # output the header line rearranged
     FNR>1 && ($NF in a){ $1=$NF; if(NF<4) { f=$2; $2=a[$1]; $3=f } else $NF="" 
     }1' B.txt A.txt | column -t
```

The output:

```
ID  a     b
1   0.01  5
2   0.1   6
3   30    2
```